# how to change the student id based on the studCode id

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to change the `id` of student based on the studCode.

Expected output:

```
student = [{
      id: '1',
      role: 'ROLE_STUDENT',
      name: 'edward'
    },{
      id: '2',
      role: 'ROLE_ADMIN',
      name: 'jake'
    }]
```

What I tried is like this but it returns [Array[1],Array[1]]
instead [object, object]

```js
const student = [{
  id: 'stud1',
  role: 'ROLE_STUDENT',
  name: 'edward'
}, {
  id: 'stud2',
  role: 'ROLE_ADMIN',
  name: 'jake'
}]

const studCode = [{
  id: '1',
  code: 'stud1',
}, {
  id: '2',
  code: 'stud2',
}, {
  id: '3',
  code: 'stud3',
}]

const _TEST = student.map(x => {
  return studCode.filter(y => y.code === x.id).map(z => {
    return { ...x,
      id: x.id
    }
  })
})

console.log(_TEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change from .map to [.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const student = [{
  id: 'stud1',
  role: 'ROLE_STUDENT',
  name: 'edward'
}, {
  id: 'stud2',
  role: 'ROLE_ADMIN',
  name: 'jake'
}]

const studCode = [{
  id: '1',
  code: 'stud1',
}, {
  id: '2',
  code: 'stud2',
}, {
  id: '3',
  code: 'stud3',
}]

const _TEST = student.flatMap(x => {
  return studCode.filter(y => y.code === x.id).map(z => {
    return { ...x,
      id: x.id
    }
  })
})

console.log(_TEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const _TEST = student.map(x => {
  const studCodeMatch = studCode.find(y => y.code === x.id)
    return {
      ...x,
      id: studCodeMatch ? studCodeMatch.id : x.id
    }
 })
```

or also

```
const _TEST = student.map(x => {
  const studCodeMatch = studCode.filter(y => y.code === x.id)[0]
    return {
      ...x,
      id: studCodeMatch? studCodeMatch.id : x.id
    }
 })
```